# Java data code formatting

Tags: java, initialization

I'm writing an android game with a lot of static data that is known at compile time. if I could develop in C I would be writing a lot of data blocks such as:

```
bank_type bank[MAX_BANK] = {
    {"GoldmanSachs", 9, "Rips your face off", 14, 1, 38, 70, 55, 18, 5,-2,-2, 2....},
    {"JPMorgan",   0, "Bunch of girls", 16, 2, 20, 34, 20, 36,-5, 3, 0, 1....},
    {"BankersTrust", 2, "Deutscher bought a lemon", 16, 2, 32, 48, 35, 30,-3,-3, 3,-1....},
    ...
```

But given I have to use java (aka one level above cobol) which doesn't support compile time data initializations I tried to do it the object oriented way and used a different class instance to store each piece of my static data but it has driven me completely insane with the number of objects involved. I have deleted all my code in a fit of madness and started again and put everything into one massive object. What I want is to keep all my data blocks together so I can see it and edit it easily. I do not want to put my data into a database nor into a xml file nor an csv file. Is there a better way to do this than writing the following because my editor is complaining that my line is too long.

```
switch (bank) {
    // in reality really really long lines spread over multiple init functions.
    case BANK1 : initData("GoldmanSachs", 9, "Rips your face off", 14, 1, 38, 70); break;
    case BANK2 : initData("JPMorgan",   0, "Bunch of girls", 16, 2, 20, 34, 20, ); break;
```

Comment: Store it in some json / yaml file, then parse it at runtime. Even if you don't want to.

Comment: change your IDE's maximum allowable line length so it stops complaining? it shouldn't be a compilation error, so you could just ignore it...

Comment: @DanAndrews I have seen `public static void main()` methods several hundred lines long : PPP

Comment: @moonwave99 I have no envy for you.  Humans sure do make coding interesting.

Comment: What about mock objects? See wikipdia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Comment: Split the data by chunks say ten edit them as they fit the page, then combine them with one move.

Answer (score 1):

Is BankType a class? You can do something like this:

```
BankType bank[] = new BankType[] {
    new BankType("GoldmanSachs", /* further args for constructor */), 
    new BankType("JPMorgan", /* further args for constructor */ ),
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: This seems almost too obvious -- I wonder why the OP wouldn't do this to start with

Comment: I tried that at first. But I understated the problem, its not simply one level. Imagine a bank level, then a department level, then team level, then individual level, each holding ~50 pieces of information.

Comment: And all of this data is static? Still you could nest creation of e.g. Departments into the BankType constructor and so on, e.g. `new BankType("...", new Department(...), ...)` but I agree with the comments above that in that case you're probably better off putting the data into a textfile and parse it at program start. Still you'll have the advantage of object oriented programming as you can parse the data into a data structure of Bank, Department etc. objects instead of having a huge multi-dimensional array.